# Javascript delegating events from div to input type range

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delegates, range

i am trying to delegate a click event from a div, which is above my input[type=range], to the range value. That means, the div behaves exactly the same way like the range-slider if i click or touch into the range-bar.

Here is my example code:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red;">
    <div id="scale" style="height: 100px;">
        Skala
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100px; text-align: center;">
        <input id="range" type="range" min="10" max="100"/>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#scale').click(function (event){
        $('#range').trigger('change');
    });

    $('#range').change(function (event) {
        console.log(event)
    });
});
```

here is the fiddle, if you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ipad0214/ouf6x3xa/2/

i hope you understand my question, what i am trying to do.

Regards, 
Patrick

Comment: You're missing reference to jQuery on your fiddle. When added, it seems to work as expected?

Comment: hej, sorry! I updated the reference and yes, but the slider is not moving anyway.

Comment: Do you want the slider to move relative to where you click in the div? As if the slider was larger?

Comment: yes, exactly! It is possible?

Comment: Added jquery and work perfect check updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ouf6x3xa/3/

Comment: Yes it is possible. Will mockup an example.

Comment: In your updated js it works perfect in fiddle

Comment: I've added a couple of simple examples below. In order to do it perfectly, you need to work out the position of the slider within the div and offset the scaling to match (left for the reader to finish) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to get the mouse position where you click (relative to the div), scale it to the range you want, then update the slider value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#scale').click(function (e) {
        var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
        var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        $('#range').val(relX).trigger('change');
    });

    $('#range').change(function (event) {
        console.log(event)
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ouf6x3xa/5/

The scaling involves taking the position clicked, relative to the width of the element then scaling and offsetting to the slider range.

This one uses the full width of the div as the slider width, but you may want it to be parallel.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ouf6x3xa/7/